# When waking up from i3lock some interaction is allowed before the password is requested

Tags: security, passwords, archlinux, lockscreen, i3

I have the following three lines in my `.config/i3/config` file:

```
set $Locker i3lock --image=/path/to/image
exec_always --no-startup-id xset dpms 600
exec_always --no-startup-id xautolock -time 10 -locker "$Locker"
```

but when I wake up the computer I have some fraction of second (maybe more than 1s) to interact with it before being prompted to insert the password, which I think is in principle a security issue, unless the behavior is expected as a consequence of my configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a result of your config file, I have the same issue with a fork of i3lock (i3lock-fancy-multimonitor) and there an [open issue on the github repository](https://github.com/i3/i3lock/issues/240). There is no fix currently.

Edit:
As of June 1, 2020, the user that opened the issue of github has posted a possible workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I use slock.

I also use it in a small script to lock my machine what is has been suspended. It locks the machine after waking up.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo /usr/sbin/pm-suspend && /usr/bin/slock
```